# dealing with hover overlay images with links on mobile touch devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, hover, tap

This is my fist post here, and it's less of a question and more of an explanation.

I searched for a long while in efforts to answer my question and I came across a lot of different answers, almost none of them right. Even when I did find the right answer, it was still partially wrong. I finally got this problem solved in what I THINK is the best way that I could. So I guess I do have a question for the community... do you have a better way to tackle this? The one problem I've noticed is that this method doesn't take into account touch devices that also have a mouse, like a touchscreen laptop and I could potentially figure a way to to activate the function on `touchstart` and not the way I did, but I don't know enough about javascript or jquery to get it to work correctly. For my purposes, this is good enough! Certainly better than anything else I tried...

So here is the situation : You have images on your site that are links with a hover function. You want someone on a desktop to be able to mouse over the image, see the hover effect, click once and be taken to the link. BUT you want someone on a mobile device to be able to tap once, see the hover effect, then tap a second time and be taken to the link.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code : https://jsfiddle.net/claytr0n/ozrLub72/8/

You'll see, as an added bonus, the proper way to integrate .webp images while maintaining a .png fall back as well to optimize image load times. I highly recommend creating .webp versions of your images if your site is almost exclusively image based like mine is!

What you want to take note of, as far as the things that helped me solve my problems and stuff I noticed along the way... giving the `:hover` events the tag `pointer-events: none;` was very important because without it, the javascript did not know whether you were clicking the text, the image, or the overlay, and would only trigger the link on 2nd tap if you happened to click the same one twice. Aiming the click function to `.rig-cell` itself will fire the link and `pointer-events: none;` on the `:hover` events keeps them from interfering.

Setting this in the javascript was the best way I found to only have the double tap happen on mobile devices and not have it happen on desktops. The previous method was activating it on touch devices but it was looking for touch enabled browsers, which I guess most are now, and was causing desktops to have to click twice to fire the link.

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Okay, that's my story! Try my jsfiddle on mobile and behold the power of managing hover events with your first tap, and firing a link with your second... on purpose! I hope someone out there finds this helpful and I can maybe save them the trouble I went through. Oh! And if you're a javascript jquery wizard and you think this is clunky or you can do better, I'm very interested to learn your ways.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Nevertheless stackoverflow is a question and answer site. Therefore please write a question and then answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer